# Reset behaviour for connected device

Tags: windows-8, mobile-phone, default-settings

When connecting my phone to my computer, the modern UI app for phones (Windows 8) automatically starts. It's probably my fault for checking this option by mistake, but I want to get rid of it. I want the default behaviour back (i.e. Windows asks me what to do with the deivce).

How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\AutoPlay`. You'll see your device there under `Devices` and you probably want to select `Take no action` from the list of possible things to do.